# Can I name the command palette title for a VS Code extension command the value of a contributed setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There is any way to set commands > title dynamically in package.json?

I have set for example "11111" in options for this extension "customPrompt1Name" and this is not work in this way as I can see.
Instead of name from `customPrompt1Name` It's a display as `${config:myapp-vscode.customPrompt1Name}`

There is any way to get title something like

`"title": "${config:myapp-vscode.customPrompt1Name}"`

in package.json without changing my extension.js

This is example of json file

```json
{
    "configuration": {
        "title": "MyApp",
        "properties": {
            "myapp.promptPrefix.customPrompt1": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "description": "",
                "order": 27
            },
            "myapp.promptPrefix.customPrompt1Name": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "",
                "description": "Your custom prompt1 name.",
                "order": 28
            }
        }
    },
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "myapp-vscode.customPrompt1",
            "title": "${config:myapp-vscode.customPrompt1Name}",
            "enablement": "editorHasSelection"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: where in the VSC doc is there a mention you can use variables in `package.json`, You can use i18n but that also is specified in the extension

Comment: was this a copy/paste of you `package.json`, it had a typo

Comment: No It's a just example.